# How do I force uninstall first?

Tags: android, installation

When I update some applications, I see some show "Manual update". I believe this will force uninstall of old version first and the installs fresh.
1. Is it true?
2. How do I FORCE uninstall of new version (with all preferences etc.), and install the new version fresh?

Answer (score 3):

The manual update isn't going to uninstall your application, then reinstall, what is happening is because the dev has changed a security requirement of the app, the user needs to agree to it again.

*So for example, if I developed a word search app with no security requirements, the user agrees to install it and uses it so decides to tick the auto update, or hits update all. My first update is simply adding puzzles - it would update fine.*

*I now add a feature to read a users SMS and their Contacts and use the internet to send me all the details.
The security privileges of my app have changed - now my app will not be included in the auto update or update all as the user needs to agree to these new security privileges and thus hopefully alerting the user to the outrages nature of the security requirements for this type of app.*

[Read More Here](http://www.androidcentral.com/froyo-feature-blocking-auto-update-apps-changed-permissions)

If what you are trying to achieve is wiping all users data, then you need to add this to your code as I don't think it is possible to do this as a market update option (I could be wrong as its not something I would normally recommend).

To do it in code, a simple look at the app version code, and if its below X then delete prefs & or DB would do the trick I would have thought.